# Deleting a job with client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes

Does anyone have any examples of how to delete k8s jobs using client-go?
I've tried the following which deletes the job but leaves the pods behind:

```golang
fg := metav1.DeletePropagationBackground
deleteOptions := metav1.DeleteOptions{PropagationPolicy: &fg}

if err := clientset.BatchV1().Jobs("default").Delete("example-job", &deleteOptions); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf(err)
}
```

I've tried using the DeletePropagationForeground option, but that resulted in nothing being deleted.

Comment: Currently running pods as part of that job? Or completed ones?

Comment: Completed ones.  I think my code marks the job for deletion but it seems like something else isn't being triggered to actually do the deletes.

Comment: To add a little more context to this, I'll describe what I'm trying to achieve.
I'm trying to write a go program that will take a video file and process it with ffmpeg as a k8s job.  I want the program to clean up the pods and jobs after itself.
I can create the jobs but it's just the cleanup that's causing me issues.

Comment: What version of k8s? Can you use `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` on the Job creation? Also requires the `TTLAfterFinished` feature gate. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/ttlafterfinished/

Comment: I've been testing this on Openshift 3.9 (so k8s 3.9).
Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd rather not have something that requires a feature gate as it should be possible without it.

Comment: that's not the foreground option "fg := metav1.DeletePropagationBackground"